# Checking Which Template Your Page Is Using

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, widget, wordpress-theming

On this page http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/blue-moutnains-and-katoomba-nsw/ my widget area is being displayed correctly (to the right hand side of the title).

I go into Quick Edit and it says I have chosen the default template and got comments turned on.

When I choose the default template and turn on comments for this page http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/grampians-victoria/ the widget area is at the bottom of the page.

To the best of my knowledge both pages would be using the page.php theme. Can anyone suggest reasons why the widget area on the two pages would be being displayed differently?

Comment: This isn't a PHP question, it's a Wordpress question, but yes, different Wordpress themes use different layouts for widget placement.  Suggest you find a theme that is close to the layout you want and create a child theme with it to tailor it further.

Comment: But to the best of my knowledge both pages would be using the same theme / template

Comment: Check the page attributes in wp-admin, while editing a page, look mid right, make sure both are using the default template

Comment: They are. I have just checked.

Comment: Install What the File plugin, it will tell you what template files are used: https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/